Website opens with different settings just before it refreshes
I made a personal portfolio site. When I open my website on a different browser, the font and other settings look differently to what I set them just 1-2 seconds before they are refreshed into the desired settings.
This is my code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>...</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Caveat:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  </head>
<body>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#projects">OS Projects</a></li>
      <li><a href="#education">Education</a></li>
      <li><a href="#experience">Industry</a></li>
      <li><a href="#awards">Awards</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <div class="main-container">
    <aside class="static-left">
      <img src="assets/AI-me2-transparent.jpg" alt="Levent Özbek" class="profile-picture">
      <div class="contact-info">
        <p>...</p>
      </div>
    </aside>

    <div class="scrollable-right">
      <section id="home" class="section">
        <h1>...</h1>
        <p>...</p>
      </section>

      <section id="projects" class="section">
        <h1>Open Source Projects</h1>
        <div id="project-list">
          <p>Projects will be dynamically loaded here...</p>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section id="education" class="section">
        <h1>Education</h1>
        <div class="education-list">
          <div class="education-item">...</div>
          <div class="education-item">...</div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section id="experience" class="section">
        <h1>Industry</h1>
        <div class="experience-list">
          <div class="experience-item">...</div>
          <div class="experience-item">...</div>
          <div class="experience-item">...</div>
          <div class="experience-item">...</div>
          <div class="experience-item">...</div>
          <div class="experience-item">...</div>
          <div class="experience-item">...</div>
          <div class="experience-item">...</div>
          <div class="experience-item">...</div>
          <div class="experience-item">...</div>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section id="awards" class="section">
        <h1>Awards</h1>
        <div class="awards-list">
          <div class="award-item">...</div>
          <div class="award-item">...</div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>


style.css
/* General Reset */
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* Global Body Styles */
body {
  font-family: 'Caveat', cursive; /* Apply the Caveat font globally */
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  line-height: 1.6;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

/* Navigation Bar */
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: 1000;
}

nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  gap: 10px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/* Main Layout */
.main-container {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
}

/* Static Left Section */
.static-left {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 30%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.profile-picture {
  width: 200px;
  height: 250px;
  object-fit: cover; /* Ensures the image scales properly within the dimensions */
  border: 3px solid black; /* Keeps the border */
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}


.contact-info {
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  line-height: 1.8;
}

.contact-info a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.contact-info a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/* Scrollable Right Content */
.scrollable-right {
  margin-left: 30%;
  width: 70%;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

h1, h2, h3 {
  font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;
}

.section {
  padding: 50px 20px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

.section h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.section p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-family: 'Caveat', cursive;
}

/* Projects Section */
#projects h1 {
  font-size: 3rem;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#project-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px; /* Add spacing between projects */
}

.project-item {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.project-item h3 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.project-item p {
  font-size: 1.4rem;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.project-item a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}

.project-item a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

/* Education Section */
.education-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px; /* Add spacing between education entries */
}

.education-item {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.education-item h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.education-item p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

/* Experience Section */
.experience-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px; /* Add spacing between experience entries */
}

.experience-item {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.experience-item h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.experience-item p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.experience-item ul {
  list-style: disc;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin-top: 10px; /* Add spacing above the list */
}

.experience-item ul li {
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

/* Awards Section */
.awards-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 20px; /* Add spacing between award entries */
}

.award-item {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

.award-item h2 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.award-item p {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

/* Scrollbar Styling (Optional) */
.scrollable-right::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px;
}

.scrollable-right::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: #888;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

.scrollable-right::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  /* General layout stacking for mobile */
  .main-container {
    flex-direction: column; /* Stack items vertically */
    align-items: center; /* Center-align content for a clean look */
  }

  /* Static-left adjustments */
  .static-left {
    position: relative; /* Remove fixed positioning */
    width: 100%; /* Full width for mobile */
    text-align: center; /* Center-align content */
    padding: 20px 10px;
    border: none; /* Remove border on mobile */
    overflow: visible; /* Ensure content is not clipped */
  }

  /* Profile picture adjustments */
  .static-left .profile-picture {
    width: 150px; /* Reduce image size for smaller screens */
    height: auto; /* Maintain aspect ratio */
    margin: 0 auto; /* Center the image */
    display: block; /* Ensures it's treated as a block-level element */
    z-index: 1; /* Bring it to the front */
  }

  /* Ensure contact info is visible */
  .static-left .contact-info {
    margin-top: 20px; /* Add spacing below the profile picture */
    font-size: 1.2rem; /* Adjust for readability */
    line-height: 1.8;
  }

  /* Scrollable-right adjustments */
  .scrollable-right {
    margin-left: 0; /* Remove margin for stacked layout */
    width: 100%; /* Full width for mobile */
    padding: 20px 10px;
    overflow: visible; /* Allow content to flow naturally */
  }

  /* Navigation */
  nav {
    position: static; /* Remove fixed positioning */
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  }

  nav ul {
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    gap: 15px;
  }

  nav ul li a {
    font-size: 1.2rem;
  }

  /* Section padding adjustments for mobile */
  .section {
    padding: 20px 10px; /* Adjust padding for smaller screens */
  }

  .section h1 {
    font-size: 2.5rem; /* Slightly smaller headings for mobile */
  }

  .section p {
    font-size: 1.2rem; /* Smaller font for better readability */
  }
}

and this is script.js:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  // Fetch and display projects from projects.json
  fetch("projects.json")
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => populateProjects(data.projects))
    .catch((error) => console.error("Error loading projects.json:", error));

  function populateProjects(projects) {
    const projectList = document.getElementById("project-list");
    if (!projectList) return;

    projectList.innerHTML = ""; // Clear placeholder

    projects.forEach((project) => {
      const projectItem = document.createElement("div");
      projectItem.className = "project-item";

      projectItem.innerHTML = `
        <h3>${project.name}</h3>
        <p>${project.description}</p>
        ${
          project.link
            ? `<a href="${project.link}" target="_blank">View Project</a>`
            : ""
        }
      `;

      projectList.appendChild(projectItem);
    });
  }
});


I did omit the personal details for brevity.
I am using dreamhost as my provider. I don't know if that has something to do with it.

The CSS changes are being reflected. The question is that, when the page first loads, the changes are not visible for a 1-2 seconds.

Sound like the google font not loaded quick enough. I'm suggest download it and host it like other files too (with minor addition in css to include the font)

Have you looked into what the &display=swap in the Google font URL actually means? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/font-display
